# Selenium with Edge Chromium in IE11 compatibility mode

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

We are trying to setup Selenium with Edge browser, but with IE11 compatibility mode in Java. Is this possible?

We tried various settings with various driver versions, setting capabilities, but with no success. Can anyone point us to a working solution example?

Thank you!